# T-SQL date between query

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

What is the most **efficent** way in T-SQL (2005) to get results from X date til today?

Attribute is `RegistrationDate` and is in date/time format, such as `Monday, July 15, 2019 12:00 AM`

I'm looking to get records where the `RegistrationDate` is from 20th August til Today, as this query would be running daily.

Current query is having some issues with this requirement:

```
cast(a.RegistrationDate as date) = cast(GETDATE() BETWEEN '2019-20-10 00:00:00.0' and GETDATE() as date)
```

Comment: 1. SQL Server 2008 ended extended support this year, I don't remember when extended support ended for 2005 but you should have upgraded your SQL Server version a long long time ago. 2. If `RegistrationDate` is a string type (`char`/`varchar`/`nchar`/`nvarchar`) no way is going to be efficient.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2005 is long out of support, why are you still using it? If you really *are* still using SQL Server 2005 it's long past time you upgrade and you really need to look at upgrade paths asap. No **supported** versions of SQL Server support an upgrade from 2005; the newest version is 2014 which is in Extended support only.

For what you're asking, however, apart from the obvious syntax errors, the `date` datatype does not exist in such as old version of SQL Server. The best method is therefore use use `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF`. I also **assume** that your statement *" is in date/time format, such as `Monday, July 15, 2019 12:00 AM`"* is misinformed; `datetime` datatypes don't have a format.

With all that I would (if I had to) do the following:

```
DECLARE @DateStart = '20190101',--First date in range
        @DateEnd = '20200101'; --First date outside of range

SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE DateTimeColumn >= @DateStart
  AND DateTimeColumn < @DateEnd;
```

If you want to make `GETDATE()` the start of the (current) day, then you would do:

```
DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

Comment: Forced to use this version of SQL due to an old, custom ERP that doesn't have any way to upgrade the SQL server version. Anyway, I like your approach, it's simple and elegant enough. For the DateEnd parameter - would it be not better to actually leave it out? And to just have DateStart as greater than the fixed August 20, and that would be it.

Comment: @Larnu Shouldn't the end date comparison be `<`, not `<=`, to include all times on the last date, but not the subsequent date?

Comment: It should be, must have typoed. Fixed, @HABO .